# How to customize array in mongdb

Tags: mongodb

I have one question in mongodb.
for example:

```
"times" : [ 
        {
            "start" : first_date,
            "end" : ISODate("2017-03-10T12:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "start" : ISODate("2017-03-10T14:00:00.000Z"),
            "end" : ISODate("2017-03-10T18:10:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "start_time" : ISODate("2017-03-11T08:00:00.000Z"),
            "end" : last_date
        }
    ],
```

This is current documentation.
I want to make this document like that

```
"times" : {
                "start" : first_date,
                "end" : last_date
            },
```

How can I do?

Comment: use $unwind operator to deconstruct an array

Comment: Do you want to change the schema or you need "times" : {
                "start" : first_date,
                "end" : last_date
            } while fetching it from database

Comment: I need it while fetching from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

Use `$arrayElemAt` to `$project` the first and last `times` value followed by another `$project` to pick the start and end time.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project:{first:{$arrayElemAt: ["$times", 0]}, 
               last:{$arrayElemAt: ["$times", -1]}}}, 
    {$project:{_id:0, "times.start":"$first.start", "times.end":"$last.end"}}])
```

You can use`$let` operator to hold the result from `$arrayAtElem` and `$project` the value in single stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$project:{"times.start":{$let: {vars: {obj: {$arrayElemAt: ["$times", 0]}},
        in: "$$obj.start"}}, 
             "times.end":{$let: {vars: {obj: {$arrayElemAt: ["$times", -1]}},
        in: "$$obj.end"}}
}}])
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you try like this..

```
     db.collection.aggregate([{
            "$unwind": "$times"
         }, {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                times: 1
            }
     }])
```

Comment: This is not what I need. it separates only times field base on _id.